# How to change Hyperlink CssClass depending on current pages filename (vb.net, asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net

I am trying to change the Hyperlink CssClass depending on a filename of current page.
Something like this:

```
Protected Sub lnkAbout_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lnkAbout.Load

    Dim CURL As String = Request.Url.ToString

    If Me.lnkAbout.NavigateUrl = CURL Then
        Me.lnkAbout.CssClass = "AboutActive"
    End If

End Sub
```

I know this doesn't work but I would appreciate if someone showed me the right way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change CssClass on the basis of the page name from where user lands on current page? that is from homepage user clicks on About page . and in about page(now the current page) there is a link which you want to give CSSClass = Home ?

Comment: I just wanted to change the Hyperlink CssClass in my webs navigation, depending of current page (ye sometihng like that, if client lands on About.aspx then the color of link About is different then the other links). Tim solved it easily. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Path.GetFileName` + [`Request.Url.AbsolutePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath.aspx):

```
Dim pageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.AbsolutePath)
If pageName = "About.aspx" Then
    Me.lnkAbout.CssClass = "AboutActive"
End If
```

(assuming that "About.aspx" is the name of the page you're looking for)

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that the issue is you assuming that the hyperlink has a load event.  Have you set a break point in your code, and if so, is it hit?

You should set the css class in the Page's PreInit event, if possible.  This is the best event to manipulate dynamic server controls/values.

Comment: Tim in the post above solved id as I needed. I just needed to get the current pages filename so I could change the CSSClass of current Hyperlink. Thanks for the information, everything's usefull. Have a nice day.